# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv

Tags: python, csv, numpy

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('FBI-CRIME11.csv')

print(df.head())
```

Running this simple code gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dita/Desktop/python/lessons/python.data/csv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.19.1-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\pandas\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import pandas.core.config_init
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.19.1-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\pandas\core\config_init.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pandas.formats.format import detect_console_encoding
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.19.1-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\pandas\formats\format.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import _get_handle, UnicodeWriter, _expand_user
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.19.1-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\pandas\io\common.py", line 5, in <module>
    import csv
  File "C:\Users\Dita\Desktop\python\lessons\python.data\csv.py", line 4, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('FBI-CRIME11.csv')
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

Comment: Can you rerun `pip install pandas` and try again?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try renaming your `csv.py` to something else, like `csv_test.py`. Looks like `pandas` is being confused about what to import.

Comment: You may also need to remove any lingering `csv.pyc` file.

Comment: Any elaboration as to why that happened?

Comment: @meow There is a builtin python module called `csv`, but having an user module by the same name has precedence and Pandas tries to import it.

Comment: Where should I look for this csv.py file? in the folder of the environment am using? (FYI- am using a virtual environment)

Answer (score 18):

Make sure you don't have a file called pandas.py in the directory you are executing your python file in.

More info in Euguene's answer in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60677039/12234134)

Comment: I actually had my script named pandas.py because I was testing pandas functionality, good tip.

Comment: I also named my file pandas.py haha seems like an occuring mistake! thanks for the tip

Answer (score 6):

I had checked for the presence of `csv.py` and made sure there was no file of this name. I also tried `pip uninstall pandas` and then `pip install pandas`. I still got the same error.

What worked for me was: `pip-autoremove`.

First install it using `pip install pip-autoremove`.
Then, remove pandas using `pip-autoremove pandas -y`.
Next, reinstall it using `pip install pandas`.

The reason why this is necessary is that sometimes, when using uninstall, the package folder may still be present.

Comment: I tried this approach. but I end up getting this :
```pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'panadas' distribution was not found and is required by the application```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Jupiter notebook and in my case I have imported and used pandas as below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('canada_per_capita_income.csv')
```

but it keeps throwing this error

> DataFrame' object has no attribute 'read_csv

then i restart the kernel and rename the csv file to

> income.csv

it solve my issue. Hope this might help someone

---

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure there are no files named `pandas.py`, `numpy.py` or `matplotlib.py`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the problem was having pandas installed using sudo. I had a situation to install the packages with sudo and changed the permissions like below

`sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/local/lib/python3.8`