# Reading csv file into Pycharm incurred error

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I just want to read a csv file into Pycharm but due to some reason it's not doing it properly.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
path = '/Users/amy/Desktop/data_analysis/additionaldata/df1.csv'
df=pd.read_csv('path', sep=',')
```

It returned error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/harper/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/harper/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/harper/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (  # noqa: F401
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amy/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amy/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 114, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amy/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 84, in <module>
    import pandas.plotting
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amy/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from pandas.plotting._core import (
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amy/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 17, in <module>
    import pandas.plotting._matplotlib  # noqa
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amy/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pandas.plotting._matplotlib.boxplot import (
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amy/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/boxplot.py", line 4, in <module>
    from matplotlib.artist import setp
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amy/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    df=pd.read_csv('path', sep=',')
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

I also tried this

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
path = '/Users/amy/Desktop'
df=pd.read_csv("df1.csv")
```

which didn't work either.

What's wrong? I have read a few other posts but still not sure how to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You could read it in with vanilla python as well.  You ever think of that as well?  Also, it looks like the `read_csv` is not under pandas, but a sub module.  Is there any submodules that look like `io` or anything?   `pd.io.read_csv` or similar?

Comment: did you try removing the path and running the code in the working directory?

Comment: Try checking whether you have given name of a python file same as pandas.This problem was mentioned in various answers(for eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696005/attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attribute-read-csv-python3-5) .

Comment: Variable `path` is defined in your code but not used, is it expected?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `open()` to open the file before passing it into `pandas.read_csv()`:

```
import pandas as pd
path = '/Users/amy/Desktop/data_analysis/additionaldata/df1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(open(path), sep=',')
```

*(Note: `'path'` is only a string with value `'path'` if you want the actual `path`, there shouldn't be any brackets.)*

Comment: Please have a look at the doc for `pd.read_csv': "pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer: Union[str, pathlib.Path, IO[~ AnyStr]], ..."  "Parameters  filepath_or_bufferstr, path object or file-like object   Any valid string path is acceptable."