# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, numpy, attributeerror

I am trying to read data from a csv file using pandas to perform regression and other statistical operations on the data but repeatedly get this error which wasn't present earlier.

```
  File "comp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 187, in <module>
    from .testing import Tester
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .main import TestProgram, main
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import argparse
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\argparse.py", line 87, in <module>
    import copy as _copy
  File "F:\mathsassignment1\copy.py", line 2, in <module>
    data=pandas.read_csv("Output.csv")
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

This is my original code

```
import numpy as np
data=pandas.read_csv('Output.csv')
```

I have tried changing it to `data=pandas.read_table("Output.csv",sep=',')`

Still the exact same error message pops up

```
File "F:\mathsassignment1\copy.py", line 2, in <module>
    data=pandas.read_csv("Output.csv")
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

Yes, it still says

```
data=pandas.read_csv("Output.csv")
```

Even after trying to read another csv file with a different name the same error message is being

I have also tried reinstalling python, running it in Ubuntu instead of Windows, reinstalling pandas, Typing the same code again in another file . I don't have a file named pandas.py in my working directory. Please help out as soon as possible .Have wasted quite a few hours trying to figure out the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read\_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554657/module-pandas-has-no-attribute-read-csv)

Answer (score 0):

In one of the first lines, you typed in

`import pandas as pd`

and later

`data=pandas.read_csv("Output.csv")`

Instead, shouldn't it be

`data=pd.read_csv("Output.csv")`

because you imported pandas as pd?

Answer (score 0):

can you rename your python file like `comp.py` to `alptekin.py`. and maybe you have some `pandas.py` file you are importing

Answer (score 0):

With the imports below, the error message `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'` disappears.

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: With a single  
"import pandas as pd" 
the error message appears.    
However why would the three imports not produce the same error message?