# How to fix AttributeError: partially initialized module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run my script but keep getting this error:

```
File ".\checkmypass.py", line 1, in <module>
  import requests 
line 3, in <module>
  response = requests.get(url) 
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'requests' has no attribute 'get' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: try to change your file name

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Make sure the name of the file is not the same as the module you are importing – this will make Python think there is a circular dependency.

Also check the URL and the package you are using. "Most likely due to a circular import" refers to a file (module) which has a dependency on something else and is trying to be imported while it's already been imported. Once it's correct, you should have something like this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://google.com")       
print(r.status_code)

# 200
```

Comment: I used the code you gave above,but I'm getting the same error can you explain more elaborately.Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have a local file with the same name as the imported module, hence it tries to recursively import itself. just rename this file.

Comment: It can happen when you already have declared your list of file to load in the \_\_all\_\_ array in the \_\_init\_\_.py' file of your module.

Modules names are already used so Python return an error

Answer (score 249):

This can happen when there's a local file with the same name as an imported module – Python sees the local file and thinks it's the module.

In my case, I had a file I created in the same folder called `requests.py`. So my code was actually **importing that file** and **not** the actual `requests` module you install with pip. Then I had another issue with a file I created called `logging.py`. I renamed both files and the issue was resolved.

Comment: I feel so silly making this mistake many times

Answer (score -3):

In my particular case, this resulted from the following sequence of commands when installing [vaex](https://vaex.io/docs/index.html):

```
conda install pydantic[dotenv]
# This failed: "import vaex" so retried pip.
pip install pydantic[dotenv]
# On "import vaex", got error in OP.
```

And the fix:

```
conda uninstall pydantic[dotenv]
pip install pydantic[dotenv] --force-reinstall
# Now "import vaex" worked perfectly.
```

Answer (score -4):

I was also getting the same error.
What worked for me is: I deleted the virtual environment and did fresh installation.
In my case some modules were installed repeatedly and I was able to see them in the venv/Lib folder which was causing the issue.