# I get an Import Error: partially initialised module with SQLCipher

Tags: python, pysqlcipher

I get the following error, when I try to use SQLCipher. I'm following a tutorial, which can be found here:
https://charlesleifer.com/blog/encrypted-sqlite-databases-with-python-and-sqlcipher/

I copied the first 2 lines which are:

```
>>> from pysqlcipher3 import dbapi2 as sqlcipher
>>> db = sqlcipher.connect('testing.db')
```

And I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'dbapi2' from partially initialized module 'sqlcipher' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Vlad\Desktop\Coding\sqlcipher.py)
```

Does anyone know what it means? And how do I fix it?

Comment: It could possibly be due to the file name your source code is in. Change it to something else that's not the same as the library name. 

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59762996/how-to-fix-attributeerrorpartially-initialized-module#60677039)

Comment: I renamed my file, but now it says that pysqlcipher3, doesn't exist. I've done installation steps up to the part with exporting CFLAGS. I don't know know what to do now. I've also installed OpenSSL from its wiki.

Comment: I couldn't do the exporting of CFLAGS as my CMD said they were unrecognised and multiple other issues.