# ImportError with import openai in conda

Tags: python, charset

I am getting this error when I import openai in Python in a conda environment:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'COMMON_SAFE_ASCII_CHARACTERS' from 'charset_normalizer.constant'

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling as mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74535380/importerror-cannot-import-name-common-safe-ascii-characters-from-charset-nor), but I keep getting the same error.