# unable to run pd.read_csv()

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis

I have an issue with pd.read_csv() for some reason I can no longer upload data.

Error: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'

```
data = pd.read_csv('MSFT-1.csv')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9236\507647841.py in <module>
----> 1 data = pd.read_csv('MSFT-1.csv')

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

Comment: Can you check the version of pandas you are using?

Comment: Is it possible you've named a python file in your project `pandas.py` or similar as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68516382/15497888) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66913583/15497888)?