# Cannot find a pandas attribute upon trying to run the code with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to ask when I receive the following error upon trying to run a code :
Pandas has no attribute `read_csv` where could be the problem if it exists in the official documentation ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\YoanIvanov\Desktop\SamplePythonProgram\Day24\U.S States\us-states-game-end (original)\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    data = pandas.read_csv("50_states.csv")
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

Comment: did you import pandas? usual way todo so is at top of your code, add: import pandas as pd. then your would do pd.read_csv(....

Comment: yes. I did but it throws the same error

Comment: not sure how your named your .py file, but check this in case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554657/module-pandas-has-no-attribute-read-csv

Comment: I think you `import pandas as pd` so try with `pd.read_csv`. From the line 0 and the line 10, did you make something like `pandas = ...` Or do you create a file named `pandas.py`?

Comment: @Corralien more likely to be the name of the file which conflict with a pandas lib. Maybe he called it pandas.py or somthing, as error code says no attribute rad_csv. check the link I posted above, likely is the reason, but will see.

Comment: just try reinstalling the pandas module by running ```!pip install pandas``` in the command prompt or terminal