# Why does a Python system package try to import a local module?

Tags: python

I just ran into a weird problem: a system package (smtplib) tries to import a local package / module. I wrote a script named "email.py" that imports smtplib, which in turn seems to try to import email.utils not from the system email package but from my script. The problem goes away if I rename the script to something else. Seems to be an easy fix, but it doesn't make sense. What if some future Python release introduces a new package that collides with a local module somewhere deep in my application?

```
~$ python -V
Python 3.11.5
~$ cat email.py
print("I AM BEING IMPORTED")
import smtplib

~$ python email.py
I AM BEING IMPORTED
I AM BEING IMPORTED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dh/email.py", line 2, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/usr/local/src/Python-3.11.5/Lib/smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.utils'; 'email' is not a package
```

Comment: I can reproduce your problem on Windows, but I do not know why it does this.

Comment: Package resolution order is the same, regardless of whether importing module is local or system. The risk is negligible, as 1) new packages are very rarely added to built-in modules and 2) it still follows normal path resolution rules. `email.py` will only be found if its at the top level. It won't be included if it is as you say "deep in your application"

Answer (score 3):

Because that's the order [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/sys.html#sys.path) works in.

`smtplib` attempts to import [the `email` standard library package](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/email.html#module-email) to do its work, but your local `email.py` is named the same and first in `sys.path`.

It's not a good idea to name any of your own modules the same as a standard library module; it'll cause issues such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/40554730/51685 too.

As for future-proofing your code, your own application should be structured to have less top-level modules and more packages (["Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/)) and you won't have a name collision problem, because the standard library won't try to import `musbur.email`.

Comment: Makes sense, and it turned out that I was on a completely wrong track. I have a module "email.py" somewhere in my package which raised an `ImportError` on `from email.message import EMailMessage` (wrong capital M). Trying to isolate the error I called email.py directly and then got hung up on the preceding `import smtplib`.